# Selenium InvalidArgumentException on opening webpage without protocol specified (http/https)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

On Windows 10 (64bit, python3.6.8), I'm unable to open link via driver's `get` method in case link was filled without `http://` or `https://` protocol specified.

I use `selenium==3.141` and `msedge-selenium-tools-3.141.2` with python.
Microsoft Edge version 85.0.564.51 (same as driver version).

The following code raises error:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.set_capability('platform', 'Windows')
options.use_chromium = True


path = r'<correct path to driver>'

driver = Edge(executable_path=path,
                    service_args=None,
                    options=options,
                    desired_capabilities={})
driver.get('google.com')
```

Error: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=85.0.564.51)`

Browser state on error - browser is launched and points to `data:,` url.

After some investigation, I found that in case I change `driver.get('google.com')` to `driver.get('http://google.com')`, issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Does the link I shared with you in my reply help you to understand the cause of the issue? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried to run the same code on another machine, it worked pretty well without any errors. For me it looks like some issues with setup or Parallels VM I used on first machine

Answer (score 0):

The main concern is, your program shouldn't be stuck with **`data:,`** in the url bar. Incase this situation happens the simplest solution would be to crosscheck the following points:

- When invoking `get()` method passing an *URL* you need to pass the [**Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). You need to ensure the url is properly formatted. As an example, the protocol i.e. `http` is appended along with the actual url as follows:

  ```
  https://www.google.com/
  ```
- Additionally, you also need to ensure that you are using compatibile version of binaries in terms of *Google Chrome Browser* and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747)

Comment: per my question, I'm sure that driver matches edge version

Comment: @BohdanKaminskyi Checkout the updated answer and let me know your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion given by the @DebanjanB.

When using driver.get("URL") method you need to compulsory pass the protocol with the URL.

If you do not pass the protocol then you will get an error.

The error might be a little bit different based on the programming language you are using.

I suggest you refer to this [document](https://chercher.tech/java/open-webpage-selenium-webdriver) and try to fully read it. It is for Firefox and using the JAVA language but the logic remains the same for all the browsers and all the programming languages. I hope it will help you to clear your confusion.